# How do I not get attacked by hired thugs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I accidentally stole a basket from the bartender at Riverwood Sleeping Giant Inn, but I gave it back yet he sent hired thugs after me. How do I defend myself without dying even though I'm level 1?

Comment: Hot Network Questions...

Answer (score 7):

Try turning the difficulty down just for that one fight and change it back to normal afterwards. The game has no trophy on PlayStation or achievements on Steam/Xbox360 relating to finishing the story on X difficulty so you won't be penalised in anyway for doing this.

I had a similar problem where Thugs attacked me as I exited the mine in Dawnstar so I turned the difficulty down by one, killed the thugs and changed it back to the default setting afterwards. On the lowest difficulty you'll take half as much damage and deal 2 times more damage than the default settings.

It is also worth noting that Bethesda probably knew this would be a problem in Skyrim as pretty much every elders scrolls and fallout games have issues where it is possible to be completely stuck because of the games mechanics.

Comment: I did though thanks, these turds are dead meat.

Comment: The game has serious balancing issues at times so you may encounter another situation where changing the difficulty will help. You could be slaughtering a dragon one minute and killed by an enemy many times smaller the next.

Comment: @ESK If this answer solved your problem, please mark the question solved by clicking the "accept" checkmark beside this answer.